# Help understanding a proof in Stallings' Triangle of Groups paper

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem 1 in Stalling's Non-positively Curved Triangle of Groups.  I have specific questions, but is there anywhere someone has written out the proof in more detail?

In the paper he eliminates from the graph of $(rf)^{-1} (T)$ curves of length less than two, but he needs to remove curves of \emph{weight} 2, did he mean weight?  Or does this somehow imply we lose curves of that weight?

Comment: Since an electronic version of this paper is not readily available, you need to give much more detail.  Preferably, quote the whole section of the proof that confuses you.  (On the other hand, if changing the word 'length' to 'weight' makes everything work, then that's probably the answer.)

Comment: This is what my advisor said, when I talked to her (after I posted this).  I just thought it was a little pretentious jus to assume the paper was 'wrong'.  It came from conference proceedings though, so I believe it was checked less thoroughly.